# MongoDB Node-Red Update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-red

I want to update data in my *MongoDB* with Node-Red using mongodb3 node.

This is my function before the mongo node:

```
var payload = msg.payload;
var newMsg = {payload: {}};

var doc = {
    $set:{
        temp:23,
        hum:99
    }
};

newMsg.payload.selector= {address: payload.address};
newMsg.payload.document = doc;
newMsg.payload.options = {upsert: true};

return newMsg;
```

I got this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: document must be a valid
>   JavaScript object.

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: API description of update: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    var newMsg = msg;
    newMsg.collection = '<insert your collection name>';
    newMsg.operation = 'update';
    newMsg.payload = { 
       {},
       $set:{
          "temp":23,
          "hum":99
       }
    };

    return newMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [mongodb3 documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-mongodb3) says about
msg.payload -

- To pass a single parameter to an operation use msg.payload as your
  parameter (eg {_id: 1243}).
- To pass multiple parameters to an    operation fill msg.payload with
  an array.
- If you want to pass a single    parameter WHICH IS AN ARRAY (eg as
  with InserMany), wrap your array    in an outer array: msg.payload =
  [[{_id: 1243}, {_id: 2345}]]

`msg.payload` is actually parameters to a operation method ('insert', 'update',...).
You can find document for parameters for all the methods [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html)

In your case:

```
var newMsg = msg;
newMsg.collection = 'collection-name';
newMsg.operation = 'update';
newMsg.payload = [
  {}, // filter
  { // update
    "$set": {
      "field to be updated": "value to be updated",
      ...
    }
  },
  {} // options [optional]
  function() {} // callback [optinal]
];

return newMsg;
```